# Loading properties as Map in a Mule Flow

Tags: mule

I am currently using Mule ESB 3.4. In-order to configure properties and load the .properties file in runtime, I use the Mule property-placeholder component. I have a requirement to extract the property values when the key itself is dynamic. For eg; I have to store the URLs for multiple applications in a properties file (like a look-up table). Here my key is the app id and the value is the URL. I need to retrieve the URLs based on the app Id which is provided to the mule-flow as part of the request. Is there a way to achieve this? The number of apps may be of the range 10-15. So I do not want to store this in a data-base and retrieve it. Is there a way to achieve it using mule via configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load them directly into a map using Spring like so:

```
 <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="appProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="singleton" value="true"/>
            <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
```

And access it dynamically in your flow using MEL similar to:

```
 <logger message="My prop #[app.registry.appProps[flowVars.someKey]]" level="INFO" />
```

Replacing flowVars.someKey with however you want to retrieve your dynamic key.

Comment: @RyanCarter Can you suggest the same for Mule 3.7 ?